# Thumbnails not appearing in either back or front end of store

Tags: magento2, product-images, magento-2.2.5, thumbnail

Weird issue. I uploaded images to each of my products and until recently, the thumbnails appeared both on the back end and the front end of Products. However, lately, that has changed and now even though I uploaded the image, the thumbnail image does not appear even though I gave it the proper role of thumbnail. Why would that be occurring? I re-indexed the database, cleared cache, pretty much everything you would expect to do. This is Magento v2.2.5.

Comment: assuming that you also ran php bin/magento catalog:images:resize , then look at the source code on the page then look to see if the image is actually stored at the path shown within the pages source code

Comment: Actually, I hadn't run that command. But even after doing so, nothing changed at all.

I then checked the URL structure and it seemed correct. Right reference to the file name. Just a blank thumbnail except for the name of the company around it. No product image.